# bootstrap drop-down-toggle misaligned row

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a prolem with the row loading odd and bigger than the previous row

Here's a [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/IxIFZZmmim)  (click name)

you can see it's loading the scroll bar odd

I want the drop to expand smoothly so it ends up inline with the above rows sorta like

```
title
----------------------------------------
|title                     |Length|Best|
----------------------------------------
|name                      |  10  | Y  |
----------------------------------------
|words                                ^|
|                                     ||
| more words                          V|
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, could you describe your problem a bit more than noting that the behavior is 'odd'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hiphop03199 apologies! updated

Comment: That's the first time I've seen an ASCII website illustration- I like it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix just add col-sm-12 to row collapse

```
<div id="description" class="row collapse col-sm-12">
      <div class="list-group-item col-sm-12 scrollDiv">
        <div contenteditable="true" onblur="">Words</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A first time question-asker answered by a first time question-answerer... I wonder if this is a first :P [Also upvoted the good response]